# Other types of closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n}$ in specific interval

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, trigonometric-series

Is there other types of closed form for the following sum?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n}$$

needs to be valid over $ 0\le{x}\le{1}$

and need to be real numbers. The form below does not work for me, because its not valid in x=0.

$$-\ln\left(2\sin \frac {x}{2}\right) $$

Comment: The series doesn't converge for $x=0$, so I would look over the "needs to be valid over $0\leq x\leq 1$" if I were you.

Comment: its a problem of heat transfer. At x=0 its my left side of the wall. So my solution, with this sumation therm needs to be valid.

Comment: then i would suspect that u made an error somewhere

Comment: i double check the calcs. The form with the ln is valid only in 0<x<1. At x=0 it goes to infinity. Every sumation has several types of closed forms. I just need other type, that is continuous in x=0.

Comment: How can any form be continuous at $x=0$ if the expression is unbounded as $x$ approaches $0$?

Comment: You can get the proper font using `\cos`, `\sin`, `\ln` and the like. For operators without a command of their own, there's `\operatorname{name}`. Regarding the content, the other comments have said it all. You can't wish away a singularity by writing the function in another form.

Comment: By the limit unicity, there cannot be "other closed forms" for such a series.

Answer (score 2):

$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}$ is converging by Dirichlet's test if $x\not\in 2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, since in such a case the partial sums of $\cos(nx)$ are bounded. With that assumption:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}=\text{Re}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{e^{nix}}{n} = -\text{Re}\log\left(1-e^{ix}\right) = -\log\|1-e^{ix}\| $$
hence:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n}= -\frac{1}{2}\log\left((1-\cos x)^2+\sin^2 x\right) = -\frac{1}{2}\log\left(2-2\cos x\right)=\color{red}{-\log\left|2\sin\frac{x}{2}\right|} $$
that is not a continuous function over $\mathbb{R}$, as expected. Things change if you consider
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(nx)}{n^{\color{red}{2}}}, $$
since in such a case you get a periodic and continuous function given by parabolic arcs, because
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$$
is the Fourier series of the sawtooth wave.

The evaluation of the previous function at $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ is one way to derive $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

for example, the summation below 
[fig1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqzSx.png)

has a closed form valid in x=0. Does exist another closed form for the summation of the topic question, valid in x=0?

Comment: Well, here the denomenator is $n^2$, so the sum is absolutely convergent. Then there will be no singularities. In your case, when the denominator is $n$, we're not as lucky as in this example.